# Removing pagination from Woocommerce product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By default, from the edit product page, Woocommerce begins to paginate product variations once you have more than 20 for a single product. How can I remove this pagination, so that all product variations can be viewed at once from the edit screen, regardless of how many there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WC set pagination as 15 variations but you can change it from below file

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-assets.php

line no 205

'variations_per_page' => absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 15 ) )

Replace 

'variations_per_page' => absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 1000 ) )
```

Comment: You're right, it is 15 per page, not 20. I'll add a function to the theme to change this without modifying plugin files, but this does work, thanks.

Comment: One would think that since there is an "apply_filters" invocation there you could simply add your own filter in to change the value.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is an absolute no-go. NEVER change plugin core files.

Please do the following:

add the following line in your functions.php (preferably in your child-theme folder too)

//Display 24 products on archive pages

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 24;' ), 20 );
```

Answer (score 4):

I achieved it thus (my use-case was to remove pagination entirely):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', function() {
    return PHP_INT_MAX;
});
```

Comment: It is worth noting that with many variations and no pagination you'll need to increase max_input_vars in your PHP.ini to something between 3.000 and 5.000. Otherwise, you will not be able to save the variations properly.
The pagination is there to limit the total amount of variables in your request.

Answer (score 1):

https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/improving-the-variations-interface-in-2-4/
The pagination restricts editing and saving to 10 variations at a time. But you can change the amount using the woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page filter if needed.

So, as per: https://www.thathandsomebeardedguy.com/increase-woocommerce-variations-per-page-in-the-admin-product-screen/ edit your functions.php and paste the snippet there.